# Why is relative path not working in python tests?

Tags: python, relative-path, setuptools, pytest, setup.py

My directory layout is as follows

```
project\
project\setup.py
project\scripts\foo.py
project\scripts\bar.py
project\scripts\__init__.py
project\tests\test_foo.py
project\tests\__init__.py
```

My test file looks as follows

```
project\tests\test_fo.py

from ..scripts import foo

def test_one():
     assert 0
```

I get the following error, when I do

```
cd C:\project
C:\virtualenvs\test_env\Scripts\activate
python setup.py install
python setup.py test
```

**E   ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package**

What am I doing wrong? 
This is my setup.py

```
setup(
    name = 'project',
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    packages = ["scripts","tests"],
    package_data={
          'scripts': ['*.py'],
          'tests': ['*.py'],
         },
)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Relative imports only work *within* a package. `scripts` may be a package, and so is `tests`, but the `project` directory *is not* (and neither should it be). This makes `scripts` and `tests` *top-level packages*. You can't refer to other top-level names using relative syntax.

Moreover, tests are not run with the `tests` package; the test runner imports the `test_foo` module, not the `tests.test_foo` module, so *as far as Python is concerned* `test_foo` is a top-level module.

`scripts` is a top-level name, just use that directly. You will have to add the `project` directory to `sys.path` however. You can do so at the top of your `test_foo.py` file with:

```
import os
import sys

TEST_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(TEST_DIR, os.pardir))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)
```

then import from `scripts` with absolute paths:

```
from scripts import foo
```

Note however that when you run `python setup.py` then your current working directory is added to `sys.path` anyway, so `scripts` is available directly without having to fiddle with `sys.path`.

Moreover, pytest will *already* do the work for you; for any given test file it'll make sure the first parent directory with *no* `__init__.py` file in it is on `sys.path`. In your case that's the `project/` directory, so again `scripts` is directly available to import from. See [*Good Practices*](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules):

> If `pytest` finds a “a/b/test_module.py” test file while recursing into the filesystem it determines the import name as follows:
>
> - determine `basedir`: this is the first “upward” (towards the root) directory not containing an `__init__.py`. If e.g. both a and b contain an `__init__.py` file then the parent directory of a will become the basedir.
> - perform `sys.path.insert(0, basedir)` to make the test module importable under the fully qualified import name.
> - `import a.b.test_module` where the path is determined by converting path separators / into ”.” characters. This means you must follow the convention of having directory and file names map directly to the import names.

Note that in order to actually use `pytest` to run your tests when you use `setup.py test`, you need to register an alias in your `setup.cfg` file (create it in `project/` if you do not have one):

```
[aliases]
test = pytest
```

Comment: after I change it to 
from scripts import foo

I get this error

(test_123) D:\Projects\project>python setup.py test
running test
running egg_info
writing project.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to project.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to project.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'project.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'project.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Comment: @user330612: I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @user330612: do note the Good Practices link in my answer though; there is info there on having to add an alias to the `setup.cfg` file before `pytest` is used to run the tests.

Comment: @user330612: without `setup.cfg` setting the alias, no tests are run, with the alias, pytest discovers the tests in `tests` and runs them.

Comment: I don't get it where should i put this code? is it in `conftest.py`?

Comment: @alial-karaawi: the point is that you don't need to do that, not when you use pytest.